# SQL rtrim select and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, ssrs-2008, trim

If you put an rtrim in the SELECT and also again in the GROUP BY, is this inefficient because its rtriming twice, one in the select and one in the group by? e.g....

```
SELECT
rtrim(people.FORENAME1)+ ' ' + rtrim(people.SURNAME)AS Full_Name,

FROM 
my table

GROUP BY 
rtrim(people.FORENAME1)+ ' ' + rtrim(people.SURNAME)
```

Comment: I guess you could simply avoid trimming in the `GROUP BY` clause and leave it in the `SELECT` clause, that should be enough to make the query sargable, as per @JNK's answer. (And don't forget to include the `people` table somewhere in the `FROM` clause.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably only performing  the function once, but **it's inefficient since it's non SARGable.**

Since you are applying a function, the optimizer can't use any existing indexes that refer to those fields.  It doesn't know the results of the function(s) until they are run, so it needs to process each and every row in the table.

Comment: Which means that...You are better off using VARCHAR() rather than CHAR() and trimming the data on input, allowing you to not need the TRIM when processing the data :)